# Which kind of geometry is needed for 3D printing (metals)?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology, 3d-printing

Generally I have more or less 3 questions when it comes to 3D printing (metals) and I am not finding the answers using Google. So, I am just asking here as I am using Blender.

It's always easy to create one mesh that has a million vertices and having all those vertices you probably make such an object (e.g. a ring) even look like it has a Class A surface.

But let's say I want to print a simple cylinder with a radius of 1 mm(!). How many vertices do I **really** need here to make this thing look round when printed?
[image]

Also, even a perfect cube will automatically be somewhat filleted when printed. The cubes here e.g. are 2*2*2 cm and the right one is beveled with an offset of 0.0001 m. Is that approximately the filleting the printer gives me for free? Or am I getting sth. smaller/larger?
[image]

Several watertight, but intersecting meshes can be uploaded as one object when using online 3D printing services. Here, all the selected faces are coplanar. This is, of course, pretty ugly geometry, but can I still assume that this will finally, when printed, give one **planar** surface?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This question is not Blender releated and you'll have more chance to find an answer on a specialised group.

To give you the beginning of an answer, I'm working with 3D printer and depending of the material, layer thickeness laser temperature, the result can be different. The only way to really now what result you will have is to print a test piece with different resolutions, sizes, printer settings to understand what fit your needs.

You could theoricaly compute the minimal number of vertices to obtain the same result from the slicer point of view, but you'll need to define what your tolerence is (because, since i'ts not the same mesh, you'll have a small difference between slices of different resolutions mesh. This tolerence can be define with the printer characteristics, but there is a lot of parameters, and it is difficult to say when the difference between two difference piece will be as low as the difference between 2 identical pieces.

So, experiments is usually the easiest way to find your needs.